# vertx 3.7.1 -> 3.8.1 no addJson function in vertx-pg-client

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, vert.x

I just upgraded my project from 3.7.1 to 3.8.1 and from io.reactiverse:reactive-pg-client:0.11.3 to io.vertx:vertx-pg-client:3.8.1

however now there is no io.vertx.sqlclient.Tuple.addJson function anymore. How can I insert json code to pg database with this driver?

I have searched on the net about this issue, but got no results.

```
private fun logWriteEvent(
    username : String,
    json : JsonObject,
    message: String?,
    path: String,
    client : PgPool)
{
    val tuple = Tuple.tuple()
    tuple.addString(path).addJson(Json.create(json))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it in the documentation: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/kotlin/